# Is there a way to disable compile checking of views that have been excluded from a project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, compiler-construction, view

I have Compile Views turned on and have just changed a big portion of my project so that a few of the views are not relevant at the moment.

I right clicked on them and chose `Exclude from project`.

However, these files are still be checked at compile time and come up in errors (as their ViewModel/model no longer exists).

The model/ViewModel themselves are excluded from the project and are not checked, but, these files will one day be included and I do not want to delete them.

So far, the only solution I have found is to highlight the entire content of the views and comment them out.

Whilst my solution does work, is this a bug or am I doing something wrong... or even, is there a better work around?

Comment: See bottom.. agrees with @ChrisF http://www.stefanprodan.eu/2011/05/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-with-visual-studio/

Comment: @Dave Mateer - I haven't tried deleting the folders, but, I have done clean and I am still getting the problem if the file is not commented - See here - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3lea4kd5dI

Comment: Good question. I used your work around of commenting out entire view. @* <div>..</div> *@

Answer (score 0):

If the files are excluded from the project then they shouldn't be compiled.

What you might have is that the object files are still the output directory and it's these that are generating the errors.

You could either clean the project **before** excluding the files or simply delete the `bin` and `obj` directories to remove all the old output.

Comment: I have already tried clean and it didn't change anything... Will try looking at the folders and manually clearing..... Is it safe to just delete these folders? (I have done bin before, never tried touching obj).

Comment: I haven't tried deleting the folders, but, I have done clean again and I am still getting the problem if the file is not commented - See here - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3lea4kd5dI

Comment: @WilliamHilsum - have you double checked to make sure that there's still not a reference somewhere to the deleted code?

Comment: there isn't anywhere - in the video, in this order : I build the project fine, then clean the project, clean the solution, uncomment the excluded file (but it is still excluded), build and I get the error.